# python Program to check whether two words are anagrams

Tags: python

I have written a small program to check whether two words are anagrams. If two words are anagrams it should return "true" otherwise it should return "False", but I am not getting the correct output. Kindly, tell me what is the mistake in the below program.

```
 def anagram(s1,s2):
     for x in s1:
         if (x in s2) and (s2.count(x)==s1.count(x)):
             pass
         return(True)
     else:
         return(False)
```

Comment: You appear to be mixing tabs and spaces for indentation - that's a [bad idea](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)

Answer (score 4):

You are iterating over a word and then not doing anything (with `pass`, the empty statement). Then you return `True` unconditionally, leaving no chance to return `False`.

Instead, you can simply sort the two words and then see if they end up the same:

```
def anagram(s1, s2):
    return sorted(s1) == sorted(s2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please format this in a more readable way. However, it looks like you are calling `return True` inside the loop, meaning that if any character occurs the same amount of times in each string, your function will `return True`

Try this:

```
def anagram(s1,s2):
    for x in s1:
        if ( x in s2 ) and (s2.count(x) == s1.count(x) ):
            pass
        else:
            return False
    for x in s2:
        if ( x in s1 ) and (s1.count(x) == s2.count(x) ):
            pass
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Note that this still doesn't produce accurate results for when a letter is in `s2` but not in `s1`.

Comment: Good catch. Updated my answer to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
>>> def anagram(str1,str2):
    s1=str1.lower()
    s2=str2.lower()
    a=len(s1)
    b=len(s2)
    if a==b:
        for c in s1:
            if c in s2:
                for s in s2:
                    if s in s1:
                        return True
            else:
                return False
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score -1):

You were really close. Your indentation was bad but that is probably due to the text formatting here in SO.

The mistake in your code was that you were returning True too soon. What you have to do is to go through all letters and check for existance and count. Below you can find a corrected and somewhat optimised version of what you were trying to do.

```
def anagram(s1, s2):
    if set(s1) == set(s2) and all(s2.count(x) == s1.count(x) for x in set(s1)):
        return True
    return False
```

But then again @Tigerhawk's solution is way better.

Comment: This has the same problem as Steve's answer (and the algorithm in the question) - it produces `True` even when `s2` has characters not present in `s1`. Try `anagram('a', 'ab')`.

Comment: i did and it returns False as expected since `set(s1) - set(s2)` is not an empty set.

Comment: Are you sure? Like, really really positive? :)

Comment: Oops. xD The local  i had locally was a checking for set equallity and not if the difference of an empty set. Sorry and thanks..